# Movie where jury gets swapped just before a trial begins?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I was having a chat this morning about jury duty and I thought of a scene from a film.

The set up is that whoever is being tried in this case has the jury paid off, and the prosecutor or cops involved discover this just as the trial is about to start.

They go talk to the judge, and he comes back in looking all shaken and orders the bailiff to swap the jury with a jury in another trial which is just about to start.

When asked how they got him to do the swap the prosecutor or cops say something like we showed him a list of names paid off, and the his (the judge) was on the list.

Can someone tell me what movie this is from?

Comment: In that case, you might have expected the prosecutors to demand the judges keep the same juries, but swap **trials.**  Think about it..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not sure if a judge has the power to do that? (or swap the jury for that matter!!) But possibly because the judge was shown that he could be exposed he would be unable to "help out" Al Capone

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is from [The Untouchables](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094226/). Kevin Costner (Eliot Ness) shows the list to the judge at the beginning of the trial of Al Capone.